# CAPTCHA is not shown at Login/register form

Tags: magento-1.9, captcha

I followed below steps to show captcha in login and registration form. But I can't see it.

1. Login to backend
2. Go to system > configuration > customers > customer configuration > CAPTCHA and select your website scope
3. Enable CAPTCHA on frontend - Yes
4. Select all forms into "Form" box
5. In "Displaying Mode" box select "After number of attempts to login"
6. Number of Unsuccessful Attempts to Login = 0
7. Save Config
8. Go to frontend and press "Log in" link

Is there any thing else left to enable captcha in login or registration form...

Comment: Install new one https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144131)

Answer (score 6):

Sadly the RWD theme has been implemented without captcha. So you can customize theme. Follow these steps:

1. Go Base theme/layout folder and copy the captcha.xml file code in your theme directory/layout/captcha.xml file in layout folder.
2. Go Base theme/template and copy the captcha directory and paste in your theme/template folder.

Thus, your captcha code will be visible.

Comment: Did as u said but still it is not showing up

Answer (score 2):

I followed this tutorial to enable Captcha for my Magento store: 
http://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-enable-captcha-in-magento

**To enable Captcha for front end**

Magento has built-in captcha for Frontend, you can enable it by navigating to System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Cunfiguration, 
Next, Select Yes for field Enable CAPTCHA on Frontend. There are a number of options here for frontend CAPTCHA.
[image]

**Enable CAPTCHA for Backend**

To enable CAPTCHA for backend, you can navigate to System -> Configuration -> Advanced section -> Admin -> CAPTCHA

**Enable CAPTCHA for contact page**
Use this free module Download the module

magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/contacts-form-captcha.html