# Captcha not show on RWD Custom theme

Tags: magento-1.9, captcha

I followed this instructions to enable captcha for registration form on site that use rwd custom theme:
https://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-enable-captcha-in-magento

And I read this post: [CAPTCHA is not shown at Login/register form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40711/captcha-is-not-shown-at-login-register-form)

and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516422/enable-captcha-on-magento-1-9

But the captcha not show.

Any suggest to solve this issue?

Comment: can u see console  for any javascript error?

Comment: No, I check it now ...

Comment: I see this: prototype.js:5644 Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
    at observe (prototype.js:5644)
    at HTMLDocument._methodized [as observe] (prototype.js:438)
    at captcha.js:54

Comment: I think you are using more than 1 jquery in your site. That may cause issue. It must be only1 jquery  in your site.

Comment: protoptype.js is core magento, how can I solve it?

Comment: I mean you are using more jquery version files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75651/discussion-between-chirag-rajput-and-joso).